# How do you remove the mirror in one of Sony's SLT cameras?

Tags: diy, sony-alpha, mirror, slt

I own a Sony α35. This camera has a [pellicle mirror](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pellicle_mirror) (semi-transparent fixed mirror) to facilitate autofocus. How do I remove the mirror to maximize the amount of light reaching the sensor when taking low-light shots? I know that autofocus will no longer work. Does removing the mirror have any risks? (Like breaking the mirror or something)

Answer (score 2):

Just my opinion, but it's not worth the possible damage you could do for half a stop. I don't think you'd break the mirror, but it's apparently at least partially made of plastic and has coatings on it.  And those you might damage. You could also affect focus alignment. Just because you can do it doesn't mean you should.

This Youtube video demonstrates the removal of the mirror from an α33:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EDhVkmxaHzw

It looks like you place the camera upside down, and then pry the mirror by the front edge of its gasket out of its housing. Very. Carefully. Not sure I'd do it with a metal screwdriver vs. a wooden or plastic tool that won't risk scratching something if it slips, but I'm a klutz.

I'd assume the procedure would be similar with the α35.